# What is the first digit of $2^{43} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

> What is the first digit of the number $2^{43}$?

I know how to do this task if it was the last digit to be calculated.

Comment: I assume you mean $2$ to the $43$, right?

Comment: My £5 calculator says 8.796093022 $\times 10^{12}$ so it's 8. (Yes, the calculator fails if it were the last digit) - I'm only adding this as you've got a non-calculator answer below which I presume is what you were really after.

Comment: @MartinHansen The nice thing about my non calculator answer is that with some more work you can extend it to say $2^{430}$ where your calculator will not work :-)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Using the fact that $2^{10}=1024=10^3\cdot(1+0.024)$ you can decompose $2^{43}=8\cdot (2^{10})^4$. I think you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an inequality of the form $$k\times 10^m\leq 2^{43}<(k+1)\times 10^m$$ where $k$ is the first digit and $m=$ the number of digits $-1$

You can get an eplixit value of $m$ 
$$m=[log_{10} \ 2^{43}]=12$$
The inequality is therefore $$k\times 10^{12}\leq2^{43}<(k+1)\times10^{12}$$ $$\implies k=8$$

Comment: How do you conclude $k=8$ from the last inequality?

Answer (score -1):

yes it will easy to find last digit. bcoz lot of sources and many ssc and banking queation ask only last digit.
here, it is also tricky question we can break 2^43 as 2^3 *1024*1024*1024*1024 as you can see multication of 1024  four times always gives 1 as leading digit. u can see thing by breaking 1024 as 1000+24 to power 4 now you will get idea after that multiply with 8 will always give 8 as leading digit.
pls leave comment if any doubt: